# Python 2D array using lists

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I'm trying to make a 2d array using lists. From input I have a tuple with the specs of the lines and the columns. Something like this.

```
((1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (9, 8, 7, 6, 5))
```

This means that i need a list like this:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

(A 5x5 matrix)

to make the matrix, since i don't know the lenth of the specs tuple. I made a constructor to make the matrix. Something like this: (t is the specs tuple)

```
t=[[0] * len(t[0])] * len(t[1])
```

This makes exacly what I want, but when I try to change a value this happens:
(y is the matrix)

```
>>>y[0][1]=2
>>> y
[[0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0]]
```

It changes all the [1] index of all the lines. Why is it doing this?

Comment: t=[] * n copies n times the reference to the single list

Comment: im so sorry for the duplicate :( Going to delete this thread